# Does a countered spell still target?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Phantasmal Dragon](http://magiccards.info/query?q=phantasmal%20dragon&v=card&s=cname) in play. My opponent casts [Unsummon](http://magiccards.info/m13/en/75.html) on it. In response, I cast [Cancel](http://magiccards.info/ktk/en/33.html) on the Unsummon. Do I sacrifice my Phantasmal Dragon because it was the target of the Unsummon, or does countering the Unsummon make it's targeting invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was still targeted.

You choose targets as part of the process of casting a spell, which has to happen before a spell can be countered. And the moment you have chosen something as a target, it has been targeted.